# Can we add non-AMP HTML inside AMP iframe?

Tags: html, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Can I use normal HTML with "img" and "script" tags using amp-iframe by calling non-amp html file using src attribute of amp-iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the iframe must be https and it will be loaded async.